# More context in the suggested edits review

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

In [this edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6439113) 2 things are not apparent from the review itself:

1. It was the asker of the question who proposed the edit.
2. The reason for the edit was mentioned in the comments (which you don't see).

I rejected this because it seems like it changed too much of the meaning/intent of the answer; it doesn't fix an obvious error, the example output is not edited, and the edit description doesn't provide too much context either.

Providing more context, such as showing the comment thread for the question, and indicating that the editor is the asker of the question (like it already does in the comments) would an improvement, IMHO.

Comment: Discussed on MSE as well: [Show the post's comments on the “Suggested Edits” review interface](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150142/show-the-posts-comments-on-the-suggested-edits-review-interface)